# Rails 5 upgrade broke delayed tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, delayed-job, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I upgraded my Rails application from `Rails 4.2` to `Rails 5.0` and now a lot of my `delayed jobs` which were created pre-upgrade are breaking. I get the following error:

`undefined method 'game_completion_feedback' for ConfirmationMailer:Class`

Even though I have the method defined in the `ConfirmationMailer` class and nothing was changed in that class or where it's being invoked from while upgrading.

On doing a `YAML.load_dj` I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError: undefined class/module ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Integer
from <path>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/class_loader.rb:53:in `path2class'
Caused by NameError: uninitialized constant 
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Integer
from <path>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `const_get'
```

It looks like it broke because something changed during the Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.0 upgrade.

I found online that running `Rails.cache.clear` can help fix this issue but my `tmp` folder in the `production` environment is empty so running `Rails.cache.clear` just throws an error as:

`No such file or directory @ dir_initialize - /var/app/current/tmp/cache/`

Is there any way that I can make these old delayed jobs still work in `Rails 5.0` or do I just have to recreate all of them individually?

My `ConfirmationMailer` class:

```
class ConfirmationMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def game_completion_feedback(user, date, feedback)
    @user     = user
    @date     = format_time(date.to_time)
    @feedback = feedback

    mail(to: user.email, subject: 'Game Completed')
  end
end
```

And I call that function as:

```
def send_feedback_to_client
  ConfirmationMailer.delay.game_completion_feedback(user, date, feedback)
end
```

This is coming up in other situations as well where I am calling a `Struct` such as:

```
class RemindersForGame < Struct.new(:gamer_email, :leader_email, :start)
  def perform
    ConfirmationMailer.game_reminder_email_gamer(gamer_email, leader_email, start).deliver_now
    ConfirmationMailer.game_reminder_email_leader(gamer_email, leader_email, start).deliver_now
  end
end
```

And I call this `struct` as:

```
def create_reminder_email(start)
  reminders = Delayed::Job.enqueue RemindersForGame.new(client.user, coach, start),
                                 run_at: start - 2.day,
                                 queue: 'game_reminder'

self.reminders_job_id = reminders.id
```

end

The `game_reminder_email_gamer` and `game_reminder_email_leader` are defined as the exact same way as the other method in that class and I didn't change anything related to how it's being called.

Comment: The [Rails Guides for Upgrading from Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.0](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#action-mailer) tells that there were some changes to Rails Mailer Interface between 4.2 and 5.0. Did you follow the guide when updating and did you make all the necessary changes?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the relevant parts of ConfirmationMailer and the Job that's calling it? Is `game_completion_feedback` method defined on a module or in the `ConfirmationMailer` class?

Comment: @spickermann I did make the changes but I will review the whole file to ensure that i am following everything

Comment: @SebastianScholl it’s defined in the ConfirmationMailer class. Sorry I had to run away from my computer for something but I will post it soon

Comment: @SebastianScholl I added the relevant code. I would appreciate any help in debugging this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For versions < Rails 4.2: `ConfirmationMailer.delay.game_completion_feedback(user, date, feedback)`

For versions > Rails 4.2: `ConfirmationMailer.game_completion_feedback(user, date, feedback).deliver_later`

Please try using this and let us know if it solves the problem.

Also, when passing variables to your Mailer class, using the `with()` method will create instance variables for you to use in the mailer instance. For example:

```
ConfirmationMailer.with(u: user, d: date, f: feedback).game_completion_feedback.deliver_later
```

Would then create `@u, @d, @f` as instance variables for use in your Mailer instance.

I'm not suggesting you name your variables as single characters :) But show that you don't need the positional arguments.

Comment: Hi, how can make these changes for `Delayed::Job.enqueue RemindersForGame` in this case? Because I get an error that `NameError (uninitialized constant Game::RemindersForGame)`. Game is the name of the class I am calling this in. Do I need to explicitly require the class with these structs in the `Game` model for Rails 5?

Comment: @anonn023432 If you're using ActiveJob, I believe that you would simply enqueue the job using `RemindersForGame.perform_later(client.user, coach, start)` or `RemindersForGame.perform_now(client.user, coach, start)`. Given that you are using Rails 5, I'd really recommend implementing this Job using ActiveJob.

Answer (score 2):

`ArgumentError: undefined class/module ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Integer` is caused by a change in Rails 5 such that `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Integer` and `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Float` don't exist anymore.  Here is a migration you can use to fix that:

```
class UpdatePostgresDataTypeInDj < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  REPLACEMENTS = {
    'ruby/object:ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Integer': 'ruby/object:ActiveModel::Type::Integer',
    'ruby/object:ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Float': 'ruby/object:ActiveModel::Type::Float',
  }

  def up
    REPLACEMENTS.each do |old, new|
      Delayed::Job.where("handler LIKE ?", "%#{old}%")
        .update_all("handler = replace(handler, '#{old}', '#{new}')")
    end
  end

  def down
    REPLACEMENTS.each do |old, new|
      Delayed::Job.where("handler LIKE ?", "%#{new}%")
        .update_all("handler = replace(handler, '#{new}', '#{old}')")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. I had to add an analogous replacement for `Date`.